# Error 404 .htaccess no muestra la página a redireccionar

Tags: php, .htaccess

Tengo el siguiente código en el .htaccess

```
#RewriteEngine
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^vercliente/(\d+)*$ ./vercliente.php?id=$1
</IfModule>

#Error
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
```

Cuando entro en una dirección incorrecta en vez de mostrar error.php me sale la típica página de error de apache de página no encontrada

> The requested URL /GestionClientes/hola.php was not found on this server.
>   Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

*¿Qué estoy haciendo mal?*

Tampoco me está funcionando las urls amigables, pero eso entiendo que va en otra pregunta.

**Edit (más información)**

Estoy en localhost, usando wamp.

**Edit 2 (Capturas de pantalla y configuración de http.conf)**

Añado captura de configuración de apache con mod_rewrite:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Añado parte del archivo de configuración del mod_rewrite

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Satisfy all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Realmente entonces no funciona nada en ese `.htaccess`, ¿estás seguro de que el servidor lo está usando?

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro como puedo comprobar que el servidor lo está usando?

Comment: ¿Has mirado en la configuración del hosting (cPanel) si no tienes activada alguna alternativa en caso de errores 404?

Comment: Estoy en localhost usando wamp.

Comment: Yo creo que tu problema es el orden , _RewriteEngine On;_ tiene que ir primero. Pero no estoy seguro , por eso no te respondo. Pero tengo curiosidad por saber como solucionarlo , .htaccess es un poco radical con las cosas.

Comment: ¿Qué servidor web estás usando?

Comment: Localhost, wamp. @SolracRagnarockradio

Comment: ¿Has verificado que estás usando la ruta correcta para error.php? ¿Dicho archivo está en la raíz o en otro folder?

Comment: @A.Cedano está en la raíz, en el mismo sitio que el index.php

Comment: ¿Y si tratas de abrir el archivo error.php desde el browser lo encuentra? ¿Puedes mostrar el contenido de tu página de error 404 en la pregunta?

Comment: @A.Cedano puedo abrir error.php sin problemas. El contenido del error está en la pregunta en fondo amarillo.

Comment: También configuré http.conf para habilitar mod_rewrite. Si quieres puedo poner el contenido de esa parte para que compruebes si está bien configurado Apache.

Comment: El error es claro: se está ejecutando el .htaccess correctamente y no se encuentra el archivo `/error.php`. Asegurate de que el archivo exista y que se encuentre en el [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html#documentroot).

Comment: @Mariano el archivo existe porque si escribo su ruta en la barra de navegación puedo acceder y verlo en el navegador sin problemas, y también está en el DocumentRoot.

Comment: @David podés hacer una de las pruebas que te recomendó A.Cedano. Para verificar que la regla funciona, cambiar en el .htaccess la línea por `ErrorDocument 404 "El error 404 funciona"`... Y, si funciona, significa que no puede acceder a `/error.php`

Comment: @Mariano no hace falta, tenías tu razón, error.php lo tenía en el mismo sitio que el index.php, no en C:\wamp64\www\ que es el DocumentRoot que me has dicho antes. Siento de veras la pérdida de tiempo que os he hecho :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error es claro: se está ejecutando el .htaccess correctamente y no se encuentra el archivo `/error.php`. Asegurate de que el archivo exista y que se encuentre en el [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html#documentroot).

Además tu otro problema se solucionaría sin usar rutas relativas. `./` puede traer problemas (especialmente con vhosts).

```
RewriteRule ^vercliente/(\d*)$ /vercliente/vercliente.php?id=$1
#                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Leyendo la documentación de apache dice lo siguiente:

> El uso de `ErrorDocument` está activado para los ficheros `.htaccess`
>   cuando `AllowOverride` tiene el valor adecuado.
>
> [<sub>Documentación de Apache</sub>](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/custom-error.html)

Por tanto:

1. Edita tu fichero  `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` para cambiar el valor de `AllowOverride` indicando dentro del conf tu documento de error, bien a través de tu archivo `error.php` :

> ```
> <Directory />
>     AllowOverride FileInfo
>     ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
> </Directory>
> ```

Bien a través de un mensaje directo (para asegurarnos de que no haya un posible error con la ruta o los permisos del fichero):

```
<Directory />
    AllowOverride FileInfo
    ErrorDocument 404 "Página no encontrada"
</Directory>
```

2. Comenta con `#` tus directivas anteriores en el `.htaccess`, para evitar cualquier redireccionamiento loco. Es decir, estas:

> ```
> #Error 
> #RewriteEngine On 
> #ErrorDocument 404 /error.php 
> #ErrorDocument 500 /error.php
> ```

Comment: Me gustaría hacerlo por .htaccess no por Apache.

Comment: Era que el fichero no estaba en el DocumentRoot. C:\wamp64\www. Gracias @ACedano

Comment: Te lo pregunté ayer: _¿Has verificado que estás usando la ruta correcta para error.php? ¿Dicho archivo está en la raíz o en otro folder?_  Me alegro de que lo hayas resuelto :)