# Acceder a .htaccess Error 404

Tags: apache, .htaccess, error404

Usando el Xampp (Apache).

Si queremos **acceder a una página en nuestro servidor web**, la cual no existe, entonces nos debe retornar un error de **Page not found**, y nos debería redirigir a una página **error404**, que tengamos nosotros diseñada, en mi caso: **error404.php**

**Código del .htaccess:**

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost:8081/daw/error404.php
```

**¿Por qué no funciona con poner únicamente la siguiente sentencia?**

```
ErrorDocument 404 error404.php
```

Muestro el directorio donde tengo los archivos, están todos al MISMO NIVEL.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: tienes habilitado el [AllowOverride](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/es/mod/core.html#allowoverride)

Comment: ¿Dónde debo configurarlo? Un ejemplo...

Comment: Mira si [esto te puede servir](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/50312/29967).

Comment: via .htaccess como te muestra @A.Cedano o via vhost eso depende de tu configuracion del servidor y no tienes info suficiente para ayudarte

Comment: ten en cuenta la respuesta que te dio @A.Cedano cambia dependiendo de la version de apache , pero de igual forma hay que habilitar el mod_rewrite

Comment: Uso Xampp, y tengo activado el Apache.

Comment: es la version del apache, agregala a la pregunta y borra el comentario

Answer (score 2):

Buenas,

Para poner la ruta relativa en el htaccess, tendrás que poner la ruta desde la carpeta matriz del localhost, es decir, desde el htdocs.

Prueba esto en el .htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 /daw/error404.php
```

Mi ruta de archivos es xampp/htdocs/cbs/mycbs/404.php

Y en mi .htaccess la ruta es la siguiente:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
Options -Indexes
ErrorDocument 404 /cbs/mycbs/404.php
```